# Spring MVC autowire issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am autowiring message source into Validator class
I have add @Component to Validator class and @Autowire to message source

```
@Component("testValidation")
public class TestValidation implements Validator {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
```

But its not injecting it. Even its not injecting any @Service annotated class to Validator class

I can see the bean object of messagesource as well as service class and Validator class when i run the following code

```
String[] beans = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String b : beans) {
            System.out.println(" ***<><><><><><><> " + b);
        }
```

Please Help !

Comment: Is ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource actually a Component too?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TestValidation is spring managed and not instantiated with new operator, it indicates your autowired annotations are not activated. Include

```
<context:annotation-config> 
<context:component-scan base-package="packageWhereServiceLocated.Service" />
```

in the context xml file.

Comment: Can you post it? And how are you calling TestValidation?

Comment: Thank you prasad!. It was the way i was calling it.

Comment: I was intializing the validator using new keyword.. That was the issue

Comment: That is the reason i asked how you are calling TestValidation. If you are instanstiating it with new, its not anymore spring managed.

Comment: Updated the answer with assumption.